# File descriptor 3 (pipe:[5141714]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 2982: /bin/sh

Tags: grub2, upgrade

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Linux-4.15.0-50-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
```

seeing strange message when running package upgrade on a server ... notice I am using parms to avoid any interactive prompt since this upgrade cmd happens with no human intervention on a remote servers

```
sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive UCF_FORCE_CONFFNEW=YES apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew -yy dist-upgrade -yq
```

strange message :

```
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[5141714]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 2982: /bin/sh
```

I see a 10 year old debian bug report which seems unresolved ... any fresh ideas ?   here is full output

```
sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive UCF_FORCE_CONFFNEW=YES apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew -yy dist-upgrade -yq
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 mdadm netplan.io nplan python3-distupgrade
  python3-software-properties python3-urllib3 software-properties-common
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
11 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 643 kB/1,314 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 netplan.io amd64 0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 [60.6 kB]
Get:2 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 nplan all 0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 [1,800 B]
Get:3 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:18.04.33 [25.1 kB]
Get:4 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:18.04.33 [107 kB]
Get:5 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mdadm amd64 4.1~rc1-3~ubuntu18.04.2 [416 kB]
Get:6 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.96.24.32.8 [9,992 B]
Get:7 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.96.24.32.8 [23.7 kB]
Preconfiguring packages ...
Fetched 643 kB in 1s (598 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 30%
Preparing to unpack .../00-netplan.io_0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netplan.io (0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) over (0.96-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-nplan_0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nplan (0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) over (0.96-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_1%3a18.04.33_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:18.04.33) over (1:18.04.32) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-python3-distupgrade_1%3a18.04.33_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distupgrade (1:18.04.33) over (1:18.04.32) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-curl_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7) over (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libcurl4_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7) over (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libcurl3-gnutls_7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7) over (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-mdadm_4.1~rc1-3~ubuntu18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mdadm (4.1~rc1-3~ubuntu18.04.2) over (4.1~rc1-3~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-software-properties-common_0.96.24.32.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking software-properties-common (0.96.24.32.8) over (0.96.24.32.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-python3-software-properties_0.96.24.32.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-software-properties (0.96.24.32.8) over (0.96.24.32.7) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-python3-urllib3_1.22-1ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-urllib3 (1.22-1ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (1.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up netplan.io (0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Setting up mdadm (4.1~rc1-3~ubuntu18.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-50-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[5141714]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 2982: /bin/sh
done
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nplan (0.97-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up python3-software-properties (0.96.24.32.8) ...
Setting up python3-urllib3 (1.22-1ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:18.04.33) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.96.24.32.8) ...
Setting up curl (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:18.04.33) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-50-generic
```

when above ran it also ran on many other remote servers with same OS release however some got above strange message others did not get that message ... super sketchy

If you also get same error please paste your output on this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1313784

Comment: I'm seeing the same message. Found your question googling for some clue about it.

Comment: @dschulz  please paste your output into linked bug report so this error gets some visibility